# Keeping data, switching scene cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In a simple game, I preload approximately 100 sprites onto a CCBatchNode, and then modify their visibility and position during the game. When the game is over I want to switch to a different scene to show High Scores, and then go back and play again. Is there a way to avoid having to reload all the sprites onto a new BatchNode?

I was also wondering how it would be best to store things like coins, that can be collected each game. Would NSUserDefaults be the best way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best solution is to use a push scene to push your scene that shows the high scores and then use popscene to pop the high scores scene from the stack. When you push and pop a scene, the underlying scene is unchanged.

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];

[[Director sharedDirector] popScene];